# Compare two AsyncAPI specifications

Tags: amqp, asyncapi

Is there a tool that compares two AsyncAPI specifications and checks compatibility? I am thinking about an equivalent to OpenAPI-Diff or Swagger-Diff.

Comment: At the moment no, I have tried to suggest Spectral to implement such [functionality](https://github.com/stoplightio/spectral/issues/1114) but it is currently out of scope for them. This is however something I would love to see in the future too. If you want to feel free to post the feature request on the [main GitHub repository](https://github.com/asyncapi/asyncapi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now an GitHub repository, and you find it on npm.

https://github.com/asyncapi/diff

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@asyncapi/diff